# Does it matter how many days have passed?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Every time I go to open my inventory to check out some new gear I found, which is approximately every 37 seconds, I see the game clock staring back at me. Sometimes it's nice to know if it's day or night since there are certain magic items that give you bonuses during the day or at night, but does the number of days elasped since the game started matter?

[image]

> - Are there any quests that have hidden a time limit?
> - Are there any events that occur after a certain day?
> - Does something bad happen if I ignore the main quest for too long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little researching on the web I can't find much evidence that the days passed has a sizable effect.

From [tvtropes.org](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/KingdomsOfAmalurReckoning):

> There don't appear to be any time limits on quests whatsoever. Even when the quest in question involves providing first aid to a woman who got knifed and is lying on the street groaning and writhing in pain.

The only thing I have found it to be useful for is farming reagents

From [trueachievements.com](http://www.trueachievements.com/a160979/green-thumb-achievement.htm?showguides=1)

> Reagents are also on a 2 day respawn (Expect for Seaflax which is 3 days), If your farming a certain reagent be sure to sleep in a bed to make it spawn again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about time limits, but I do know there are different outcomes depending on elapsed time. For example, working on my file I waited forever to do a quest I got at the beginning of the game. It was the "find brother Eagan" mission; when I finally did it he was simply dead at a location.

A few days later I was working on my sons file and did the same quest as soon as I accepted it. It had a totally different outcome...I found brother Eagan and had to go steal something and then fight the 2 'fake faes' who were deceiving him, ending it with successfully bringing him back to the monastery. I've had this happen on a few different quests.

So yeah, the longer you wait (especially when others well-being is involved) the more of a chance you have at a not so happy ending. So I learned the hard way to just do one mission at a time and NOT accept anymore along the way.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't noticed much of an in-game affect of the time, other than the world being darker at night, and light during the day. Frequently in towns the people are asleep at night, but you can still talk to them but they won't have anything different to say (still selling items if a vendor, turn in quests, etc.).

So I don't think that the time of day makes much of a difference really.

Comment: Actually, time of day  (night vs day) matters for quite a few magic items. But what I'm really curious about is not time of day, but number of days that have passed.